# Basic authentication with CouchDB

Tags: curl, couchdb

I am trying to figure out how to use basic authentication (i.e. `http://test:test@localhost:5984/mydb`) in CouchDB 1.3.1.

In the Futon:

- I create a database `mydb`
- I setup two users for it. In *Security* tab: one member with read access `["test"]` and one admin `["admin"]`

Then i just test connection.

**Using curl:**

```
curl GET http://localhost:5984/mydb
```

returns `401` unauthorized, that's good.

```
curl GET http://test:test@localhost:5984/mydb
```

returns `200`, so everything works as expected using curl.

**Using browser or $.ajax:**

Both return `401` on the url `http://test:test@localhost:5984/mydb`.

**So, questions:**

- What is the difference between using `curl GET` or usign `$.ajax GET` (or browser)?
- Am i missing some configuration in CouchDB or somewhere else that allows to perform this kind of authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Basically, there's a limitation placed on the ajax calls a browser can make. It's a security feature that doesn't allow the browser to load resources from anywhere arbitrarily.

It seems like you would want to be able to do that, after all a click loads an arbitrary resource. But if any old javascript program could load any other resources there are a lot of ways that it could be hijacked to inject code or steal information.

CURL gets around that by not being limited by CORS. It just makes any old request you'd like.

Additionally, you can start a session by querying localhost:5984/_session, at which point all of your following queries will be sent with a security token cookie. [jQuery.couch](http://daleharvey.github.io/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/) is a nice basic resource for some common functions.

Comment: never thought the 401 could be a cors problem. Tested through a reverse proxy and voila.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put the authentication information in the header. Try it!

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb', //Your api url
      type: 'GET', //type is any HTTP method
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
       headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('MyUser:MyPassWord')
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var resposta = response            
            },
            error: function (err) {
                var t = err.responseText;
                console.log("Erro de requisição: " + err.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Source: https://zinoui.com/blog/ajax-basic-authentication